# Grafana: Get last N minutes events count

Tags: spring, grafana, spring-micrometer

I use Spring Micrometer to count every occurrence of a specific event (using [counter](https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_counters)).
How can I get the difference between the counts between now and N minutes ago? I need to how many events were occurred in the last N minutes.
I Grafana I can find only `count`, `m1_rate`, `m5_rate`, `m15_rate` and `mean_rate`.

Comment: Do you want to specify it in a lucene query? I mean - a query that hits the counts from now until now-N?

Comment: mircometer requires a back-end for storing the metrics. Which backend you are using for storing metrics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was looking for - change of counter value for last 10 minutes.

```
diffSeries(sum(path.to.metric.count),timeShift(sum(path.to.metric.count),'10min',true,false))
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your datasource. I don't know Micrometer, but looking at the docs, it seems it publishes metrics to Prometheus, so that is your datasource. If that's correct, you could use something like `count_over_time(metric[1h])`. That gives you the number of samples for that metric in the specified time interval. I think "m1_rate" and the others are metrics created by Micrometer.